# Xamarin forms Carousel view does not allow skipping position

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, carousel

So i am trying to implement a wizard using carousel view that has next and previous buttons. For some reason the carousel view does not allow me to navigate multiple positions. For example if the view is currently at position 0 and i want to jump to position 2 it will go to position 1.

So view in xaml:

```
<CarouselView CurrentItemChanged="CurrentCarouselItemChanged" x:Name="EventWizardCarouselView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
            <views:EventBasicInfoView x:Name="eventWizardViewEventBasicInfo"/>
            <views:EventRulesView x:Name="eventWizardViewEventRules"/>
            <views:EventLocationsView x:Name="eventWizardViewEventLocations"/>
        </x:Array>
    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>

private void OnNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    EventWizardCarouselView.Position = 2;
    OnPropertyChanged("Position");
}
```

Moral of the story here is that when in position 0 and i programatically set it to position 2 it will display position 1? However from position 1 it will go to position 2 just fine?

Comment: any fix for this issue?

Comment: @Suchith works in ios android but still issue for UWP

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this on UWP by turning off animation. This is more of a band-aid than a fix but works for now. For those that run into this note that animation is set to true by default and i had to use ScrollTo(index, groupindex, type, false).

Answer (score 1):

On Android, set the `CurrentItem` property of the carouselview. On iOS, set the `Position` property. Something like this code:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) {
    var selected = YourViewModelCollection[2];
    EventWizardCarouselView.CurrentItem = selected;
} else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS) {
    EventWizardCarouselView.Position = 2;
}
```

Comment: What about UWP?

Comment: Sorry I can't answer for UWP

Comment: Give up on UWP ... even the demo programs from the developers don't work!  The CarouselView CurrentItem and CurrentPosition events only get called (wait for it) every THREE presses of the right or left positioning keys!  How can I develop when this stuff is playing such games??!!?  Come back OpenVMS - all is forgiven ...

Comment: The iOS option worked for me but the Android option did not.  For Android it just goes to the beginning of the list whether I use Position or CurrentItem.  Then the user just has to scroll to the position he wants.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of way to change position of **CarouselView** , however the effects of animation all will show the middle position when skipping position.

**[One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction)** is using `CurrentItem` or `Position` , they all can used in Android /iOS even in UWP (if no problem when running UWP).

- **CurrentItem**, of type `object`, the current item being displayed. This property has a default binding mode of `TwoWay`, and has a `null` value when there isn't any data to display.

eg : `carouselView.CurrentItem = viewmodel;`

- **Position**, of type `int`, the index of the current item in the underlying collection. This property has a default binding mode of `TwoWay`, and has a `0` value when there isn't any data to display.

eg :`carouselView.Position= position;`

**[Another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#scroll-an-item-at-an-index-into-view)** is using **Scrolling** .

```
carouselView.ScrollTo(position);
```

or

```
carouselView.ScrollTo(ViewModel);
```

**Note :**

Not too much focus on `UWP` , because **[CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/introduction)** is available on iOS and Android, but some functionality may only be partially available on the Universal Windows Platform.

And `CarouselView` is a **preview** Control which statrs available in Xamarin.Forms 4.3.

Comment: What do you mean by "however the effects of animation all will show the middle position when skipping position"

Comment: I have tried setting position, current item, and scrolling and no matter what i end up on position 1 instead of two. This is UWP btw

Comment: @Maxqueue Okey , I mean the animation in iOS and  Android , however not sure in UWP . I have seen you found a solution to fix this , that's great !  About this phenomenon , this should be partially available on the Universal Windows Platform. It's unfortunate to occur this and not sure whether solution will always work later .

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the "real" solution for this problem, but I developed a quick workaround that looks nice enough.

In my app I got 3 tabs. Moving by 1 tab works fine so I just check if I want to got from the first to the last or the other way round and then just make it two movements:

```cs
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS 
    && Math.Abs(oldIndex - newIndex) > 1) // Tab index is changed by 2?
{
    _carouselView.ScrollTo(1);

    // Second move after delay
    Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
        _carouselView.ScrollTo(newIndex)), 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
}
else
{
    _carouselView.ScrollTo(newIndex);
}
```

No customer complained so far :-)

Comment: This is for UWP?

Comment: @Maxqueue No, for iOS. But I think it should also work on UWP if you just replace (or add) RuntimePlatform with Device.UWP